# Mayavi undesired blue-red channel switch over VNC

Tags: python, colors, vnc, mayavi

I'm experiencing an issue where the R and B channels are swapped in Mayavi figures.

I'm connecting to a remote machine (machine 2) via VNC (`vncserver` yields `DISPLAY=:1`, so I'm connecting to a newly allocated X session [?]) and running `mayavi 4.4.3` on that remote machine.

Below is an example. Plotting a figure with `bgcolor=(1,0,0)` yields a blue figure (middle figure), `(0,1,0)` yields a green figure (right figure, expected), and `(0,0,1)` yields a red figure (left).  (Ignore the beige, which was due to dragging the figure windows above one another)

[image: BGR in mayavi]

I've tested this on my local machine (machine 1) with `mayavi 4.1.0`, and gotten the expected results of a red figure from `(1,0,0)` and a blue figure from `(0,0,1)`, so the issue may lie with the remote machine. Again, the remote machine's Mayavi version is `4.4.3`. Additionally, I've tested this on my local machine (machine 1) over VNC from a separate server (machine 3), and gotten the expect result, so it appears it can render correctly over VNC. I've also tested on machine 2, the problem machine, locally, with `DISPLAY=:0` (the original display), and the problem is not present.

Here's an additional example of creating a Figure and plotting a point

[image: point plot mayavi]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by using:

`remote@remote$ vncserver -pixelformat bgr888`

instead of

`remote@remote$ vncserver`